# How secure are Cordova apps?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, security

I wonder if it is a good idea to go for a mobile app using Cordova.

On the one hand it is pretty easy to address even a number of mobile target platforms.

On the ther hand it is just a WebPage with JavaScript attached.
Each WebBrowser for the a Desktop offers nowaday the possibility to enter DebugMode and unveils the interna of the browsed page including the JavaScripts.

Can that also happen to my app, which I have distributed as Cordova package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, anyone can download your App from the store and extract the HTML and JavaScript files from the IPA. This is not really related to security but more of a DRM type of issue. Unless you have proprietary content/code/algorithms within these files, you should not worry about someone looking at them.

Using a native App (Objective-C / Swift) does not really prevent that either, as someone can download the App and disassemble the binary (using a tool like Hopper http://hopperapp.com/) to look at the compiled code. It is a bit harder but still definitely do-able.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the javascript and html from a desktop browser (chrome for android or safari for ios) if you built the app in debug mode.

I don't think you can access the js of an app installed in release mode (may depend on each platform) but if you release your app as a free app on the playstore, then anyone can easily download the apk of the file and get all the js and html as easily as opening the apk in a zip program.

Comment: How shall I understand your answer?   Is there something I as a develop can do to prevent or support leaking?